# How do I insert values from an HTML form into a 'txt' file for retrieving it again using ajax?

Tags: html, ajax

Retrieving data from AJAX. How to insert values from an HTML form into a 'txt' file for retrieving it again using AJAX?

Comment: what do you mean into a txt file. locally or to the server?

Comment: i mean on the pc itself ( local )

Comment: are you using nodejs or trying to do this in a browser?

Comment: doing it in browser only

Comment: Check out the html fs api http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/